# Database name in an AWS Arora Postgres Serverless cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I have created a new Arora Serverless PostgreSQL cluster and I am trying to use the Query Editor.

What do I enter in the Database Name text field? Where do I find the name of the database? Is it the same are the cluster name? [image]

Note: I have enables the Data API when I created the DB

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creation of database is an optional setting when you create your Aurora serverless:

[image]

If you haven't done that you have to create your db using traditional way.

Comment: Strange that this is an optional setting? Why would you make a cluster and not a DB?

Comment: @DrkStr Sometimes you may not need to create it at the same time. But usually, people create it when they create the DB instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the name of the database within the cluster, not any hostname or individual node. The target hosts are specified in `Database instance or cluster` label.

When you created your database cluster you could optionally specify a database that would be created on the host. This default database is viewable from within the console interface. Otherwise if you created the target database after the cluster launched, specify that database name instead.